# Making a picturebox (GIF) appear for x amount of seconds then dissapear

Tags: c#, visibility, picturebox

In a single method how can I (in sequential order):

```
public void method()
{
    picturebox1.visible = true;

    //wait 2 seconds;

    picturebox1.visible = false;
}
```

probably really easy to answer but my brains fried right now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
public async void method()
{  
     pictureBox1.Visible = true;

     await Task.Delay(2000);

     pictureBox1.Visible = false;

}
```

Comment: Is there some sort of namespace i have to use? Intellesence doesnt like "async" or "await"

Comment: No, just make sure your Framework version is 4.5, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
public void method()
{
    picturebox1.visible = true;

    //wait 2 seconds;
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    picturebox1.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: This will block the UI thread, so your application will become unresponsive. It's better tu use await Task.Delay(2000);

Comment: Yes.. If you want UI will remain responsive use Task.Delay()